# How can I run a node.js script as multiple scripts? no impact on each other

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a node.js application that get some bot telegram token and run them as a bot. 
I use telegraf module. 
But when a bot receive too many request or throw an error and then crashed, this happen for the others bot. 
What can i do to solve this problem.  
I want the bots to be separate from each other. 
A way is Copying my code and run the bots as multi script separately. 
But i have many bot so it's impossible.

Here is my code to run the bots:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
var {Robots} = require('./model/models/robots');



var botsList = [];
setInterval(() => {
    Robots.find({bot_type: 'group manager'}).then((res) => {
        if(res.length > 0){
            var tokens = [];
            for(var i = 0 ; i < res.length ; i++){
                var newToken = res[i].token;
                tokens.push(newToken);
            }

            var bot = [];

            tokens.map(token => {
                if(!botsList.includes(token)){
                    botsList.push(token);
                    var botUserId = token.split(':')[0];

                    bot[botUserId] = new Telegraf(token);

                    module.exports = {
                        bot
                    };

                    const Commands = require('./controller/commands/commands.js');

                    bot[botUserId].on('text', (ctx) => {
                        Commands.executeCommand(bot[botUserId], ctx);
                    });

                    bot[botUserId].startPolling();
                }
            });
        }
    }).catch(console.log);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the error in one broker to not affect the script as whole, you can just handle the error using [process.uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) handler for the script.

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', console.log);
```

If you want to go a step further and create child process for each bot to run in. Use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module provided by Node.

```js
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

fork('./bot.js', token);
```

Here, the `bot.js` can have all the bot related code.

Hope this helps!